# How can "for instance" create a comma splice?

Tags: grammar, commas, comma-splices

**Example sentence**

Take Bartlett 29 pears for instance, unless they are treated with exactly the right amount of 1-MCP at exactly the right time, they will remain hard and green until they rot, and consumers who experience this will be unlikely to purchase them again

According to a book, this sentence has a comma splice due to the phrase "for instance"

I was wondering how is this so? The sentence seems fine to me.

Comment: @Bread I agree that a full stop would be better than a comma there. I disagree with the OP's book that the phrase "for instance" is the reason the comma is awkward there: removing "for instance" doesn't help.

Comment: @Lawrence ~ I can't argue with that; but in any case, the OP doesn't give a source for the book cited. **For instance** modifies Take Bartlett 29 pears -- which should have been a separate sentence anyway.

Comment: @Bread *alleged* book, then. :)

Comment: A colon after _for instance_ makes more sense to me than a period.

Comment: A colon seems the obvious choice, since the sequence beginning "unless they are treated ..." expands the topic of "Bartlett 29 pears".

Comment: I'd go for a semi-colon personally. But I'm in agreement with everyone else that there shouldn't be a comma there!

Answer (score 1):

I would have written it like this: **Take Bartlett 29 pears, for instance. Unless they are treated with exactly the right....** I agree that the comma is not appropriate there, because it alters the meaning of the sentence in a way that is unintended, judging from the context.

The reason is that with the comma, **unless** sounds more like a modifier for first main clause, rather than the beginning of a second main clause. The two main clauses need to be constructed as two separate sentences:

- **Take Bartlett 29 pears**, for instance.
- Unless they are treated with exactly the right amount of 1-MCP, at exactly the right time, **they will remain hard and green** until they rot, and consumers who experience this will be unlikely to purchase them again.